# Saving a view with nscoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I implemented the two methods of the protocol nscoding in a view controller, but now I want to save the view when the apps close and restore the view when the apps start, how I do this?

Comment: After posting the basically same question over and over again, I really suggest reading a good book on programming, and the iPhone Development guides provided by Apple. What you are doing here is just the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: No it's not the same question, I implements the methods(encodeWithCoder, initWithCoder) like in the IPhone development guides, but what to do after? On a other answer on the forum it's write to save and restore the controller with a nskeyedArchiver, but I don't find exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NIB to ensure that the view objects are always loaded as required, then just configure them in the view controller's -viewDidLoad method.